# what is the smartest way to add all variants to product category page in shopify

Tags: shopify, variant, shopify-template

I am looking at showing all Shopify `product variants` on the `product collection` page.  We are using the basic theme.  What is the easiest way to do this?  I have looked at some examples but none of them are exactly what I need.

I am not scared to edit liquid files, etc... but prefer to keep it as clean as possible.

Comment: Searching the web for _"shopify show all variants on collection page"_ shows plenty of hits, what have you tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58496976/displaying-variants-options-in-collection-page-shopify, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37236612/show-all-color-variants-on-collection-page-in-shopify-using-brooklyn-theme

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the most useful solution: https://dylanjh.com/blogs/18-show-all-variants-as-separate-products-on-the-collection-page-on-the-minimal-theme